# drag and drop angular order not changing

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

i create form builder based on this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-survey-creation-golkhg, and i use this function for droped

```
onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.surveyForm.get('surveyQuestions')['controls'], event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

the `questionTitle` must changing, but it was not

[image]

but in the html it's changing

[image]

the order of the array is changing in html, but in my json is not changing, can someone help me?

EDIT

After a while i don't touch this code again, i found some error,please see this before and after images, here's before

[image: Before]

```
"quizQuestions": [
    {
      "questionType": "File Upload",
      "display_order": 1,
      "questionGroup": {
        "questionTitle": "",
        "quizAnswer": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "questionType": "Tanggal",
      "display_order": 2,
      "questionGroup": {
        "questionTitle": "",
        "quizAnswer": ""
      }
    }
  ],
```

after i dragged the first form, it looks like this

[image: After]

```
"quizQuestions": [
    {
      "questionType": "Tanggal",
      "display_order": 2,
      "questionGroup": {
        "questionTitle": "",
        "quizAnswer": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "questionType": "File Upload",
      "display_order": 1,
      "questionGroup": {
        "questionTitle": "",
        "quizAnswer": ""
      }
    }
  ],
```

what's is wrong actually? i've tried both of the best solution you guys provide but it's still like this, please help me out. Note: i change surverysQuestions to quizQuestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add display_order property in your formGroup and you can see order change in that property.

And in onDrop method change the display order of the other questions. something like this:

```
onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
   moveItemInArray(this.surveyForm.get('surveyQuestions')['controls'], event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
   this.questionFormArray.controls[event.currentIndex]['controls']['display_priority']
            .setValue(event.currentIndex + 1);
   this.questionFormArray.controls.forEach((category, index) => {
            (category as FormGroup).controls['display_priority'].setValue(index + 1);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add changeDetectionStrategy to your component

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

Comment: something like this https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/?

Answer (score 0):

Method example:

```
onDrop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
   moveItemInArray(this.surveyForm.get('surveyQuestions')['controls'], event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  this.surveyForm.get('surveyQuestions').updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: false });
}
```

Comment: Its much better when you left any comments for your answer

Comment: whats the different with gourav solution?

Comment: updateValueAndValidity allows you to modify the value of one or more form controls and the flag allows you to specify if you want this to emit the value to valueChanges subscribers. After moveItemInArray method you need to use updateValueAndValidity method, no need to do it manually.

Comment: hey i just try your solution, but both of you and the other guys solution it's a bit strang in view, in json it's perfect though, please see my EDIT really need your help